# Strings in ternary operators interacting with numbers

Tags: java, string, parsing, if-statement, double

If I have an if statement that includes a string like this:

```
double GUInumber1 = ((GUInumber1 >= 0 || <= 0)? Double.parseDouble(GUIfirstNumber) : 0);
```

('GUIfirstNumber' is the string)

Why does it come up as a error? Do I need brackets somewhere, do I need to use 'If/else' instead?

Supposedly my compiler says it does not recognize or (`||`), is this supposed to be something else or does this work in a completely different way.

Any help on this situation would be appreciated, also, if you need to know or are just wondering why I want to make a if statement for a string its because whenever I try to put in a letter instead of a number Java crashes, I'm hoping I could get this to alternatively solve the situation instead.

EDIT:

Solved, had to remove 'or' statements and alternatively make more else statements instead.

Comment: This is not an if statement, it's a ternary operator. In addition, (GUInumber1 >= 0 || <= 0)  makes no sense to a computer. A computer sees those two things either side of the "||" as an expression. GUInumber1 >= 0 is an acceptable expression,  but <= 0 doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression `(GUInumber1 >= 0 || <= 0)` is not correct.

You will need something on both sides of the `<=` operator.